# Python switch off failures' show. Pytest how to fail silently. Suppress traceback of assert

Tags: python, pytest

In my python program I don't need to see the source code of some of my fails when the exception is thrown. How do I suppress their output? I still want to return the error code.(to CI)  I just don't need long stack of calls that caused my error. I just want pytest to show FAILED and return nonzero code.

I'd like to implement it, and I tried these two functions:

1. `pytest.skip()`: but it doesn't return nonzero code.
2. `pytest.fail()`: but it shows big traceback

What should I use to hide some exceptions?

Comment: You can control the traceback format via the `--tb` argument, e.g. `pytest --tb=no` et voila. Another possible values are `auto/long/short/line/native`, try them out to see what fits your needs most. If you don't want to enter the option each time, store it under `addopts` in your `pytest.ini`.

Comment: @hoefling , that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!